# paste special method of range class failed error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

While doing the second paste I'm getting an error 1004, can anyone please help, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Copy 
lr = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
wb2.Sheets(1).Range("B"& lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wb1.Sheets(1).Range("F1:F5").Copy 
wb2.Sheets(1).Range("C"& lr).Pastespecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: "lr" gives integer value for the next empty row

Comment: [This is a better way to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba), but seems unrelated to the RTE 1004.

Comment: Start at the bottom and search up, Most likely you do not have data in B2 and when you do  `lr = wb2.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row + 1` you are going to the bottom of the page and trying to paste one row off the bottom of the page.  See the link in @BigBen comment.

Comment: You also need to specify the sheet in `wb2` for `lr`.  `lr=wb2.Sheets(1).`

Comment: i tried the way @BigBen mentioned but it still gives error for this line wb2.Sheets(1).Range("C"& lr).Pastespecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

Comment: `lr = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: @ScottCraner I wrote the exact line before, it seems the error still there.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print lr` return in the Immediate Window? Are there protected cells on `wb.Sheets(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted your code with this addition:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook: Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2")
Dim lr As Long
```

But it worked correctly.

I suggest checking this:

- walk through the code with F8 and verify what is in the variables
- make sure that the part you're copying to isn't protected